# difficulty in matlab to python code conversion

Tags: python, matlab

I am converting matlab code to python code

```
function Xn = ReSampleCurve(X,N)

    [n,T] = size(X);
    del(1) = 0;
    for r = 2:T
        del(r) = norm(X(:,r) - X(:,r-1));
    end
    cumdel = cumsum(del)/sum(del);   

    newdel = [0:N-1]/(N-1);

    for j=1:n
        Xn(j,:) = interp1(cumdel,X(j,1:T),newdel,'linear');
    end
```

I want to convert this into python code

The input values are :

```
X = [[-9.035250067710876, 7.453250169754028, 33.34074878692627], [-6.63700008392334, 5.132999956607819, 31.66075038909912],[-5.1272499561309814, 8.251499891281128, 30.925999641418457], [-5.1272499561309814, 8.251499891281128, 30.925999641418457]]
N = 200
```

can anyone explains me what these lines do?

```
    del(1) = 0;
    for r = 2:T
        del(r) = norm(X(:,r) - X(:,r-1));
```

Comment: you can always try http://freemat.sourceforge.net/ and run the matlab-code to see for yourself...

Answer (score 1):

`del` is an array in the MATLAB code. So `del(1) = 0` is equivalent to `del_list = [0]` (MATLAB arrays a 1-indexed, `del` is a reserved word in python).

In the for loop, this is equivalent to:

```
for r in range(1,T):
    del_list.append(norm(X[:,r] - X[:,r-1]))
```

The above won't work in pure python (array subtraction won't work). You'd have to add in numpy or numeric) - but hopefully you get the idea.

Answer (score 1):

For what it is worth, here is the vectorized way to get `del(2:end)` in Matlab, perhaps this makes more sense to you:

```
sqrt(sum(diff(M,1,2).^2))
```